# Parse the json data and get the count of each data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to parse the json data and want to get the count for Leadstage.Now I want to get the count leadstage based geo.

```
 {
    "Geo" :"US East"  
    "LeadStage": "SGL",
    "count": 6
  },
```

Partial working with my code.
need to get based on geo also.

```js
 var data = {
   "leads":{
      "data":[
         {
            "UserName":"Tharun Sairam",
            "Geo":"US East",
            "LeadStage":"SGL"
         },
         {
            "UserName":"Tharun Sairam",
            "Geo":"US East",
            "LeadStage":"MGL"
         },
         {
            "UserName":"Praveen Kumar",
            "Geo":"US West",
            "LeadStage":"SGL"
         },
         {
            "UserName":"Souvik bhattacharya",
            "Geo":"US East",
            "LeadStage":"SGL"
         },
         {
            "UserName":"Denisse Morales",
            "Geo":"NSU",
            "LeadStage":"MGL"
            
         },
         {
            "UserName":"Souvik bhattacharya",
            "Geo":"US East",
            "LeadStage":"SGL"
            
         },
         {
            "UserName":"Souvik bhattacharya",
            "Geo":"US East",
            "LeadStage":"SGL"
            
         },
         {
            "UserName":"Souvik bhattacharya",
            "Geo":"US East",
            "LeadStage":"SGL"
            
         },
         {
            "UserName":"Anthony Susairaj",
            "Geo":"US West",
            "LeadStage":"RGL"
            
         },
         {
            "UserName":"Vivek Sharma",
            "Geo":"NSU",
            "LeadStage":"SGL"
            
         },
         {
            "UserName":"Souvik bhattacharya",
            "Geo":"US East",
            "LeadStage":"SGL"
            
         },
         {
            "UserName":"Arvind Partha",
            "Geo":"US West",
            "LeadStage":"SGL"
            
         },
         {
            "UserName":"Kaviarasan Selvaraj",
            "Geo":"NSU",
            "LeadStage":"SGL"
         },
         {
            "UserName":"Tharun Sairam",
            "Geo":"US East",
            "LeadStage":"MGL"
           
         }
      ]
     } 
};

function groupByLeadStage (arr) {
                        var groupBy = {};
                        $.each(arr, function () {
                        groupBy[this.LeadStage] = 1 + (groupBy[this.LeadStage] || 0);
                        });
                        return groupBy;
                    }
                    function createArray(obj){
                        var arr = [];
                        Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key){
                        arr.push({
                        LeadStage: key,
                        count:obj[key]
                        });        
                        });
                        return arr;
                    }

                    var resObj = groupByLeadStage(data.leads.data);
                    var resArray = createArray(resObj);
                    console.log(resArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: checkout `reduce()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), in this case you can do without JQuery

```js
const data = {
    leads: {
        data: [
            {
                UserName: 'Tharun Sairam',
                Geo: 'US East',
                LeadStage: 'SGL',
            },
            {
                UserName: 'Tharun Sairam',
                Geo: 'US East',
                LeadStage: 'MGL',
            },
            {
                UserName: 'Praveen Kumar',
                Geo: 'US West',
                LeadStage: 'SGL',
            },
            {
                UserName: 'Souvik bhattacharya',
                Geo: 'US East',
                LeadStage: 'SGL',
            },
            {
                UserName: 'Denisse Morales',
                Geo: 'NSU',
                LeadStage: 'MGL',
            },
            {
                UserName: 'Souvik bhattacharya',
                Geo: 'US East',
                LeadStage: 'SGL',
            },
            {
                UserName: 'Souvik bhattacharya',
                Geo: 'US East',
                LeadStage: 'SGL',
            },
            {
                UserName: 'Souvik bhattacharya',
                Geo: 'US East',
                LeadStage: 'SGL',
            },
            {
                UserName: 'Anthony Susairaj',
                Geo: 'US West',
                LeadStage: 'RGL',
            },
            {
                UserName: 'Vivek Sharma',
                Geo: 'NSU',
                LeadStage: 'SGL',
            },
            {
                UserName: 'Souvik bhattacharya',
                Geo: 'US East',
                LeadStage: 'SGL',
            },
            {
                UserName: 'Arvind Partha',
                Geo: 'US West',
                LeadStage: 'SGL',
            },
            {
                UserName: 'Kaviarasan Selvaraj',
                Geo: 'NSU',
                LeadStage: 'SGL',
            },
            {
                UserName: 'Tharun Sairam',
                Geo: 'US East',
                LeadStage: 'MGL',
            },
        ],
    },
};

const result = data.leads.data.reduce((acc, lead) => {
    const tryFind = acc.find(l => l.Geo === lead.Geo && l.LeadStage === lead.LeadStage);

    if (tryFind) {
        tryFind.count++;
    } else {
        acc.push({ Geo: lead.Geo, LeadStage: lead.LeadStage, count: 1 });
    }

    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `reduce` and take `Object.values` of it after the process done:

```js
var data = { "leads":{ "data":[ { "UserName":"Tharun Sairam", "Geo":"US East", "LeadStage":"SGL" }, { "UserName":"Tharun Sairam", "Geo":"US East", "LeadStage":"MGL" }, { "UserName":"Praveen Kumar", "Geo":"US West", "LeadStage":"SGL" }, { "UserName":"Souvik bhattacharya", "Geo":"US East", "LeadStage":"SGL" }, { "UserName":"Denisse Morales", "Geo":"NSU", "LeadStage":"MGL" }, { "UserName":"Souvik bhattacharya", "Geo":"US East", "LeadStage":"SGL" }, { "UserName":"Souvik bhattacharya", "Geo":"US East", "LeadStage":"SGL" }, { "UserName":"Souvik bhattacharya", "Geo":"US East", "LeadStage":"SGL" }, { "UserName":"Anthony Susairaj", "Geo":"US West", "LeadStage":"RGL" }, { "UserName":"Vivek Sharma", "Geo":"NSU", "LeadStage":"SGL" }, { "UserName":"Souvik bhattacharya", "Geo":"US East", "LeadStage":"SGL" }, { "UserName":"Arvind Partha", "Geo":"US West", "LeadStage":"SGL" }, { "UserName":"Kaviarasan Selvaraj", "Geo":"NSU", "LeadStage":"SGL" }, { "UserName":"Tharun Sairam", "Geo":"US East", "LeadStage":"MGL" } ] } };

var result = Object.values(data.leads.data.reduce((acc, {UserName, ...rest})=>{
    const key = Object.values(rest).join('|');
    acc[key] = acc[key] || {...rest, count:0};
    acc[key].count++;
    return acc;
},{}));

console.log(result);
```